# Using css in html2image(java)

Tags: java

I tried to use html2image lib but when I save the html to a image, the background and css dont be show in the image. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

There is a issue as posted on the home page of site, which says;

> The formatting in the HTML is not preserved

Please see the home page for details:
http://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/issues/detail?id=1